# How to use STDIN twice from pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, pipe

I have a awk script something like

```
awk 'FNR==NR {col1[$1]++; col2[$2]++; next} {print $0, col2[$2] "/" length(col1)}' input input
```

But in case I have lot of files and need to use this script for concatenated files together like:

```
cat *all_input | awk 'FNR==NR {col1[$1]++; col2[$2]++; next} {print $0, col2[$2] "/" length(col1)}' STDIN STDIN
```

Does not work. How to use STDIN twice from pipe?

Comment: Your question makes no sense at all. If you are cat-ing many files to awk via stdin? why would you need to pass stdin again at end. You got the understanding wrong

Comment: ..and why are you changing the question completely after asking another requirement first?

Comment: Sorry for wrong description, but it seems | into the <(...), twice works perfectly fine. Script looks: awk 'FNR==NR {col1[$1]++; col2[$2]++; next} {print $0, col2[$2] "/" length(col1)}' < (cat *files) < (cat *files)

Comment: But if that's what you "need" then you don't need that. Even if you didn't want to store the lines in memory or in a temp file (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44688094/1745001) you could get the same output with simply `cat *files | awk '...' - *files` and no process substitution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use a pipe. If you are using `bash` use [process-substitution as `<(cmd)`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) i.e. to achieve a redirection where the input or output of a process (some sequence of commands) appear as a temporary file.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {col1[$1]++; col2[$2]++; next} {print $0, col2[$2] "/" length(col1)}' <(cut -f3 5- input) <(cut -f3 5- input)
```

Comment: Thank you Inian - but what if I have lot of files and need to do something like: cat *files | awk ....... STDIN SDTIN?

Comment: @Geroge: The requirement from your above comment is not clear. Explain with an example and add it to the question

Comment: Good to know for process-substitution!! But I little change my question to concatenate my files..

Comment: Just move whatever you have before `|` into the `<(...)`, twice.

Comment: You cant always replace a pipe with process substitution because you can't always run the same command multiple times to produce the identical input multiple times. I'm surprised the OP accepted this answer but the example in the question is a bad example of the general case so maybe what he said he wants (`How to use STDIN twice from pipe`) isn't what his example shows he actually wants (`how to execute awk on multiple files`?). Oh well....

Answer (score 3):

The answer to `How to use STDIN twice from pipe` is "you can't". If you want to use the data from stdin twice then you need to save it somewhere when you read it the first time so you have it next time. For example:

```
$ seq 3 |
awk '
    BEGIN {
        if ( ("mktemp"|getline line) > 0) tmp=line; else exit
        ARGV[ARGC]=tmp; ARGC++
    }
    NR==FNR { print > tmp }
    { print FILENAME, NR, FNR, $0 }
' -
- 1 1 1
- 2 2 2
- 3 3 3
/var/folders/11/vlqr7jmn6jj3fglyl12lj0l00000gn/T/tmp.Y03l9pS7 4 1 1
/var/folders/11/vlqr7jmn6jj3fglyl12lj0l00000gn/T/tmp.Y03l9pS7 5 2 2
/var/folders/11/vlqr7jmn6jj3fglyl12lj0l00000gn/T/tmp.Y03l9pS7 6 3 3
```

or you can store it in an internal array or string and read it back from there later.

Having said that, your specific problem doesn't need anything that fancy, just a simple:

```
cat *all_input | awk 'FNR==NR {col1[$1]; col2[$2]++; next} {print $0, col2[$2] "/" length(col1)}' - *all_input
```

would do it but unless your files are huge all you really need is the store-it-in-array approach:

```
awk '{ col1[$1]; col2[$2]++; f0[NR]=$0; f2[NR]=$2 }
END {
    for (nr=1; nr<=NR; nr++) {
        print f0[nr], col2[f2[nr]] "/" length(col1)
    }
}' *all_input
```

Comment: Hi Ed, thank you for good point. You understood my question right. Would be possible to put into array this modification of awk script: awk 'FNR==NR{a[$90];b[$1]+=!c[$1,$90]++;next}{print  b[$1] "/" length(a) "\t" (b[$1]/length(a))*100}' <(cat *anot_tmp1.tsv) <(cat *anot_tmp1.tsv)  ?? I would like to apply your solution for huge files thank instead of use substitution..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. If you have a huge files why would want to store their contents in an array instead of using the data directly from the files? You selected an answer so you should ask the person who provided that answer instead of someone like me who provided the wrong answer - maybe they'll understand what you mean and have a tweak for you to their answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that can help because I am not an awk expert, but any Linux application (including awk) can read stdin straight from **/proc/self/fd/0**

Note that this is way less portable than open(0) and will only work on Linux with readable procfs (nearly all Linux distributions today).

if the application allows for parallel file descriptors consumption, you can open that file descriptor twice and read from it twice.

**self** in the path designates the PID of the accessing application.